# URL Scheme for SMS and phone call

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I have a `href` on a webpage that used to work on `IOS6` perfectly, since the IOS7 update the link now does not work. I can only assume `Apple` has removed this feature or not yet incorporated it.

```
<a href="sms:07884412345">Send Sms/Text</a>
```

Can anyone suggest other ways of displaying a link on a page that either calls the mobile number `OR` opens up the send SMS message view on an iPhone that uses IOS7.

I have tried the following:-

```
<a href="sms:07884412345">Send Sms/Text</a>
<a href="sms://07884412345">Send Sms/Text</a>
<a href="tel:07884412345">">Call me</a>
<a href="tel://07884412345">">Call me</a>
```

It should be noted that it still works ok on WP8 and Andriod phones.

**edit** It looks like if you save the page as a home page icon and open it doesn't work. Not sure why that is and can't confirm it.... Back to testing...

**edit 2** At this point I will mention I am using Kendo UI mobile and when you save the page as home page icon and then reopen from home screen the hyperlinks don't work.

What an obscure bug, will raise a ticket with Kendo. Sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i tested it on a device with iOS 7:

```
<a href="telprompt://07884412345">Call me</a>
<a href="sms://07884412345">Send Sms/Text</a>
```

Comment: sorry my question had a typo I have tried `sms://`, however I will try again.

Comment: +1 thanks for testing, looks like if you save it as a home page icon and open it doesn't work as intended.